# How to draw suit and rank in uiview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to create a card game and I need to draw the card suit and rank in the top left and the bottom right using drawRect function but I don't know how to draw spade, clubs, heart and diamond can you help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either search for some images on the internet and use them in a `UIImageView`, or take advantage from the fact that the suit symbols are included in [Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/miscellaneous_symbols/list.htm) and use a `UILabel` to draw them.

An alternative for the second method is to use the [`drawInRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawInRect:withAttributes:) method of `NSString`.

Comment: The images will take space in memory, and the unicode is either white or black and I need it to be red for heart and diamond

Comment: They won't take that much space - they're simple mono-colored images. If you want red text, you can always change the `textColor` of the label.

Comment: Ok but how to draw it using drawRect?

Comment: Use the [`drawInRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawInRect:withAttributes:) method of `NSString`.